# Middle align table cell content of a right floated span with different font size

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having problems to "middle" vertical align of a span with a different font size than the table cell itself.

What I want to achieve is this layout:

`|                                                           |
| Measurement (font-size: 100%)        unit (font-size: 70%)|
|                                                           |`

So my markup looks like this:

`<td class="value">Performance <span class="unit">kW</span></td>`

The `unit` span is right aligned in the cell using `float:right` and the whole cell is styled with `vertical-align:middle`. The `unit` class uses a smaller `font-size:70%`. Both together do not work. It seems the floating style aligns the `unit` span on the top where the `Measurment` text starts to draw.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lszdx2hd/

Removing the floating style from the second span in this jsfiddle demonstrates the effect.

So is there an easy way of achieving the layout I want without much more markup and without floating styles? I tried relative positioning but then I cannot vertical center the `unit` span it seems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If it is just about the relative alignment of the elements, float them both and make the `line-height` of the second span twice as high as the `line-height` of the first as it has 50% of the `font-size`. cf. http://jsfiddle.net/Lszdx2hd/1/

```
span {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  float: left;
}

span + span {
  font-size; 50%;
  line-height: 2;
  float: right;
}
```

this way it will work independent of the font-size and/or height of the first span.

Comment: Thanks. It seems this screws up the rendering of the table.

Comment: Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lszdx2hd/2/it still works if we use a table. I guess there is something missing from your fiddle.